# Dynamic queries with DataMapper

Tags: sinatra, ruby-datamapper, slim-lang

I would like to be able to make dynamic queries with DataMapper ,for searching an Sqlite database for my Sinatra project.Is it possible?
So far I have come up with something like this trying to get the songs that are sang from the artist specified by the named parameter:

```
get '/artists/:name' do
@artist = Artist.get(params[:name])
@songs= Song.all(:artist_name => '#{artist.name}')
slim :show_artists
end
```

These are my DataMapper Classes:

```
configure:development do
    DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/3sbase.db")
    DataMapper.auto_migrate!
end

class Song
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :title, String
    property :year, Integer
    belongs_to :artist
end

class Artist
    include DataMapper::Resource
    #property :id, Serial
    property :name, String, :key=>true
    property :age, Integer
    has n, :songs
end




DataMapper.finalize
```

and this is my .slim file

```
/show_artists.slim

h1= @artist.name
p Age: #{@artist.age}

- if @songs.any?
    ul#songs
      -@songs.each do |song|
        p <a href="/songs/#{song.id}">#{song.title} </a>
- else
  p There are no songs from this artist/band in the database.
```

Every time the if statement returns false and so I get the "There are no songs from this artist/band in the database." message despite the fact that there are songs sang by the  artist I search for in my database.

Comment: After asking in the sinatrarb google group I was suggested to change 

**@songs= Song.all(:artist_name => '#{artist.name}')**

  with this line:
  
  **@songs= Song.all(:artist => {:name => @artist.name})**
  
So problem  solved though I am not sure yet why it should be written this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking in the sinatrarb google group I was suggested to change

```
@songs= Song.all(:artist_name => '#{artist.name}')
```

with this line:

```
@songs= Song.all(:artist => {:name => @artist.name})
```

or with this

```
@songs= @artist.songs
```

they both work fine